# Do deleted questions affect reputation?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, deleted-questions, reputation

So I was scrolling through my reputation tab, to see my rep breakdown and I noticed a post that has like 45+ rep, but when I clicked to see the page was deleted. I do not know why it was deleted though, seems cool but that is not my question. My question is why is it that this [post](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/42726/its-happening-somewhere-in-the-future/42727#42727) is deleted but its reps adds up to my whole rep count.

So does reputation accumulated on a deleted question have an effect on your whole reputation?

If not, why? Because if someone posts something and gets a ton of downvotes and later deletes the question it does not change, same for upvotes.

Comment: For an answer, specifically?

Comment: yes Sir, for this questions its about an answer, but i want to know the general rule here, because its a little different from what i know on other sites here, @Catija

Comment: I'm not a sir... The rules are the same on all SE sites. I believe it has something to do with how long the post exists before it's deleted... If the post is made and deleted within a couple of days, it's one thing, but if the post exists for a while, like a week or month or something, the rep stays. I can't find any documentation, though.

Comment: yes, yes, i missed that, the answer has the docs/post for it, Thanks too Madam  Catija :) @Catija

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this related answer on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/162011) the reputation gained from the votes on a deleted post is *not* removed if **it's at least 60 days old and has a score of at least 3**.

> Reputation changes from bounties, votes (both up and down), and acceptances on deleted posts (including answers to a deleted question) are nullified. (Exception: Reputation earned for posts with a score of three or higher, and where the post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days, [is retained](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/)).

This is the case on each and every SE site.

Comment: hmm, guess i missed that. Thank you Sir. hope you are a Sir :)

Comment: Yes, I am.. ;-)

Comment: @checkMyProfile Don't forget to accept the answer if it is the correct solution to your problem.